# How to use a R class?

Tags: r, class

[image]I need to use the class `IntVP` from the `volesti` package in R.

This class allows to find the intersection between the two V-polytopes that are defined by df1 and df2. The intersection is `(5,1)`.

I thought IntVP was a function, however it seems it is a class. How can I use it with my arguments

```
df1 = matrix(c(6,1),ncol = 2)
df2 = matrix(c(5,4),ncol = 2)

A1 = rbind(df1,c(-1,0),c(0,-1))
A2 = rbind(df2,c(-1,0),c(0,-1))
```

When I create a new object:

```
last = new(IntVP, A1,A2)
```

I can only get the arguments, but not the actual result of the intersection.

Comment: What do you mean by *to use*? The question is not clear, please give an example of what/how you are trying to do.

Comment: I would suggest asking the package maintainer: https://github.com/GeomScale/volume_approximation I don't get the sense that you're supposed to use `IntVP`.

Comment: Maybe I am just too new in the use of classes. But if I understand well, this only creates an object, right?

Comment: You don't "use" a class. It's just a blueprint of what an object should be composed of in order to be properly used by a package's set of functions.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the documentation for this class. Can you clarify then what I can or cannot do with it?

Comment: Only people who use this particular package can answer this, which is why I would recommend reaching out to the package maintainer.

Comment: OK, I will do this. Thank you!

Comment: I think that the problem is that that class is not a `R` class. You can't "use" a R class, you just can assing them to some ojbects in order to apply some methods. I think `IntVP` is a C++ class, but I don't really understang how could you get what you want. It would be a good idea to ask the mantainer of the package and ask if the function you are looking for is missing

Comment: indeed, when I create the new object, and then I ask ```class(newObject)``` I get this ````> class(last)
[1] "Rcpp_IntVP"
attr(,"package")
[1] "volesti"````

Answer (score 1):

From the author of the package:

You will need the R version of package `volesti` for the intersection of two V-polytopes.
You should use the function volume. Store the vertices of the polytopes, row-wise, in two matrices `V1, V2`. Then define the polytope as below,

```
P = IntVP$new(V1 = V1, V2 = V2)
```

However,

`volesti` does not compute the vertices of such a polytope. You can compute (approximately) the volume or sample from it.